How to access a static JSON file from the server from a react app
I have a static JSON file in my apache server and I want my react application to access the static JSON file and show its content
The idea behind is I have a Terms and Condition page in my application my react application will cover all the skeleton (App bar, logo, Navigation buttons ..) of the T&C  page but I want the content of my T&C page to be loaded from the static JSON file that  I place on my server so that if I want to make any change to the T&C I only update the JSON file and no need to rebuild my application
FYI - I am using create react app and not webpack
How do I achieve this?

what have you tried so far?

Why not just fetch it?

"FYI - I am using create react app and not webpack"... CRA uses Webpack

I created a static HTML file and fetched it from my AWS I moved away from the idea of using JSON

Just fetch the file.
let [jsonData, setJsonData] = useState();

async function loadData() {
    let res = await fetch("url");
    setJsonData(await res.json());
}

useEffect(() => {
    loadData();
}, []);

You may want to add error handling.
